# Decipher the clues, escape the prison!

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

## Decipher the clues, escape the prison!

The guard at the prison, where you have been locked up for [misuse of USB ports](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/internet-security/11932793/Killer-USB-stick-destroys-your-computer-in-seconds.html), has given you one chance to escape, by typing in a certain word. A keyboard is put down in front of you, and you are shown a sheet that reads as follows:

> You never know where the key will be hidden, it could be *right
>   between your eyes*...
>  `[20][1E][23][1F]`
>
> **THE WORD**
>
> Much like a Vigenere cipher, yet the letters are numbers!
>
> `[1L][1H][2M][16][13][08][06][17][15][18][10]`

What should you type in?

**HINT 1**

> The part about 'right between your eyes' applies to the word only, not the text in the first code block.

**HINT 2**

> The guard is quite nice and has given you, being a **USB expert**, nothing too hard.

**HINT 3**

> Surely *someone* knows a cipher like a Vigenere cipher but with numbers as letters.

Comment: "right between your eyes" refers to either "nose" (the length of which matches the exact amount of [] blocks in the first row). or it is some red herring... hmm...

Comment: @BojidarMarinov or it might be the letter 'G' coz it is in the middle of the keyboard in all the alphabets.

Comment: @BojidarMarinov That is not a bad trail of thought!

Comment: @BojidarMarinov Also read 'Hint 1'.

Comment: Hint 2 is **very important**, especially the bit about you being a **USB expert**...

Comment: Pretty sure he's referring to a Gronsfeld cipher.

Comment: @dpwilson Of course it is!

Comment: I feel like I'm close, but I just can't figure out the "USB expert" hint. :/ I've looked at the USB logo, read quite a few USB "fun facts". Skimmed through the Wikipedia page, but found nothing of use. One thing I thought about was whether the presence of a keyboard has a significance. Maybe the alphabets used in the Gronsfeld cipher are "QWERTY.." instead of "ABCDE..". I've tried changing letters to numbers by having E = 0, M = 8; E = 1, M = 9; letter = number of its column on keyboard (e.g. QAZ all = 1) - to then have numbers between 0-25 or 1-26 in the square brackets, but that didn't work.

Comment: I could not quite understand what Hint 1 is about.

Answer (score 5):

I think the word is

> **SPECTRUM**

The first block is

> just a hint that the encrypted text is base 16.

Since I am a USB expert,

> I know how to read in base 16. And when I convert the legal blocks in `[1L][1H][2M][16][13][08][06][17][15][18][10]` from base 16 to base 10, it results as `22 19 8 6 23 21 24 16`. When we convert these decimal numbers to letters in English alphabet, we get `WTIGXVYQ`.

Then, by using

> Caesar cipher, I shift the letters by 22 to get **SPECTRUM**

Comment: Interesting find, but I suspect this is only a partial answer, since it doesn't make use of the first code block, nor does it use a Gronsfeld cipher.

Comment: Does the second part not count as Gronsfeld? I think first block is just a distraction

Comment: Converting bases is not Gronsfeld. Caesar is a special case of Gronsfeld, but I doubt that's what the question is referring to. I hope the first block *isn't* a red herring, but then what do I know?

Comment: Not about converting the base, but converting numbers to Letters, as far as I know is Gronsfeld.  I might be wrong, of course.

Comment: Gronsfeld is [Vigenere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) but using numbers instead of letters.